# What's wrong with "Ellos acaban de llegar a la casa."

Tags: gramática

I am taking a Spanish class on Coursera. I can't get the following question right, any idea why? I feel my answer is a legit sentence.

Given the pattern:

> Ellos / acabar de / llegar / casa

I am writing:

> Ellos acaban de llegar a la casa.

However, it says it is not correct:
[image]

Comment: ...llegar a casa?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, your answer could be valid provided that the sentence does not refer to their *home*, but to a *house*.

Example:

> Ellos acaban de llegar a la casa [que tienen alquilada].

You can omit the part between brackets if you already know by context that the sentence refers to a rent house. But if the sentence refers to their *home*, the article is omitted:

> Ellos acaban de llegar a casa.

Comment: I don't think it matters if the house is rented, rather if it is "home." "They just arrived home," vs "They just arrived at the house."